Check if child exist in firebase database and return true or false
I want to create method that will check if a child is present or not in firebase database and returns the value true or false accordingly. here's my code
public boolean check_if_child_exist(DatabaseReference reference, String child){
        boolean if_exist;
        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot datasnapshot) {
                if(datasnapshot.hasChild(child)) {
                    if_exist = true;
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                if_exist = false;
            }
        });
        return if_exist;
    }

I have tried below code but it didn't work
if(datasnapshot.hasChild(child)) {
    return true;
}


Loading data from Firebase is an asynchronous operation, and while that is happening yourj main code continues to execute. This means that your return if_exist; executes before the if_exist = true; or if_exist = false; executes, something you can most easily verify by setting breakpoints or adding some logging. The only solution is always to put all code that needs the data in the onDataChange/onCancelled, to call it from there, or to otherwise synchronize when the code executes. I linked some answers explaning more about this...

Try this-
public boolean check_if_child_exist(DatabaseReference reference, String child){
        boolean if_exist;
        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot datasnapshot) {
              if_exist = datasnapshot.hasChild(child);
                     
             }  
         
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                //Leave this blank or show/log error
            }
        });
        return if_exist;
    }

